# How to sync up a folder in amazon S3 with people in Austria

Tags: macos

My business is digital retouching here in the Pacific Northwest, and I have several photographers in Austria who I work with. Typically, both of us have macs running Maverick.

I would like to have one folder for each client that both of us can put images in and  out. I would like to use my Amazon S3 account like dropbox. My file sizes are large, like 20 to 30 gb

How do I go about setting that up with my Amazon S3 account? My level of experience is newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend either 3Hub or Forklift in the App Store. If that is not what you are looking for, I can also use https://github.com/timkay/aws. It is command line only though.